# Creating a nonperiodic function in mathematica

Tags: functions, function-construction

I want to create a non-periodic square wave with values of 1 and -1(not necessarily alternating).

For e.g. I want to convert an arbitrary array like {1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1} into a function.

I tried using Piecewise but I don't know how to do this without typing a huge number of conditions.

I also want to add the length of each stack(i.e. the duration for which it is in 1 or -1)
e.g. two inputs value={1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1} and duration={5,6,1,2,3,8,2}

Please Help

P.S: The version I am using is 8.0.4.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The edited question indicates that the function is supposed to be defined based on *two* lists - one for the values and one for their respective durations. Here is how you could do that:

```
vals = {1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1};
duration = {5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 8, 2};

f[v_, d_][x_] := 
 Piecewise@
  Transpose[{v, (#[[1]] <= x < #[[2]] &) /@ 
     Partition[Accumulate[Prepend[d, 0]], 2, 1]}]

Plot[f[vals, duration][x], {x, 0, 40}, ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: piecewise]

The `duration` list is treated with `Accumulate` to get the absolute positions from the durations, and then a list of start and end points for the corresponding absolute intervals is created using `Partition` with an offset of `1` so that the end point of one interval is the start of the next. Then, `Piecewise` defines the whole thing as a function.

To plot the function with its vertical jumps displayed as lines, I set `ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic`.

Answer (score 10):

Define a function:

```
f[x_, dat_] :=  Total@MapThread[#1 UnitBox[x - #2] &, {dat, Range[Length[dat]]}]
```

Test it on periodic data:

```
per = Cos /@ Range[0, 10 Pi, Pi]
{1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1}

Plot[f[x, per], {x, -1, 13}, AspectRatio -> 1/5, Filling -> 0]
```

[image]

Test it on non-periodic data:

```
aper = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 50];
Plot[f[x, aper], {x, -1, 53}, AspectRatio -> 1/5, Filling -> 0]
```

[image]

See the magnificent expression behind it - so you don't have to type it by hand ;) -

```
PiecewiseExpand[f[x, aper]]
```

[image]

In the above formula you can see discrete values 2 and -2 coming from the fact that `UnitBox` is defined as 1 at both of its boundaries. So the perfect definition of your function would really be with `Clip` added:

```
f[x_, dat_] :=  Total@MapThread[#1 UnitBox[x - #2] &, {dat, Range[Length[dat]]}]//Clip
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I also want to add the length of each stack(i.e. the duration for which it is in 1 or -1)

Answer (score 7):

Try `Interpolation` with `InterpolationOrder->0`, like so:

```
Plot[Interpolation[{1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 0][x], {x, 1, 7}]
```

[image]

You can generalise and randomise like this:

```
mysquarewave[n_Integer?Positive] := 
 Interpolation[RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, n], InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

And then do things like this:

```
 Plot[mysquarewave[10][x], {x, 1, 10}]
```